# Cannot add or update on child row

Tags: mysql, sql

My project just has two tables and the problem is that I can't add more than the entry that's already there:

```
select from acceso>

+----+---------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| id | ip            | date                | bloqueado | categoria | comentario |
+----+---------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | 201.214.164.5 | 2018-05-31 01:16:10 |         0 |         1 | NULL       |
+----+---------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+

select from categoria>

mysql> select * from categoria;
+----+---------+
| id | nombre  |
+----+---------+
|  1 | general |
+----+---------+
```

This is the script I changed:

```
drop table categoria;
drop table acceso;

CREATE TABLE categoria (
    cat_id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE acceso (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ip VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
date datetime NOT NULL,
bloqueado tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
categoria int(11) NOT NULL,
comentario TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES categoria(cat_id)
);
```

When I try to add to the "acceso" table it throws "cannot add or update on child row...":

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`c9`.`acceso`, CONSTRAINT `acceso_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `categoria` (`cat_id`))
```

As you can see in this last entry I'm not trying to add anything different to the categoria table nor is there any difference between the two ids but there must be something else I'm not aware of.

EDIT: Now I got it. The FOREIGN KEY points at a wrong column (acceso.id instead of acceso.categoria).

```
CREATE TABLE categoria (
    cat_id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE acceso (
id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ip VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
date datetime NOT NULL,
bloqueado tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
categoria int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
comentario TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY (categoria) REFERENCES categoria(cat_id)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made cat_id INT UNSIGNED, because that is how it is on parent table

```
CREATE TABLE categoria (
    cat_id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE acceso (
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ip VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    date datetime NOT NULL,
    bloqueado tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    categoria int(11) NOT NULL,
    comentario TEXT,
    cat_id INT UNSIGNED ,
    INDEX par_ind (cat_id),    
    FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES categoria1(id)
);
```

Comment: @ffuentes, I see..Tried something like this? 
insert into acceso (ip, date, bloqueado, categoria, comentario)
values ('202.213.145.4','2018-05-31 01:16:10',0,1,'');

Comment: ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`c9`.`acceso`, CONSTRAINT `acceso_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `categoria` (`id`))
mysql>

Comment: As it is the script didn't work for me. I changed the id of categoria to cat_id but it still throws the same error.

Comment: are you able to create your child table just fine? Or did you have any difficulty when creating the child table?

Comment: When I rerun the script it works well. The thing is I can't add more than one entry on acceso.

Comment: @ffuentes could you please try the Updated scripts? I have made cat_id INT UNSIGNED, because that is how it is on parent table.